# Opencsv how to set the column size with automatic text size

Tags: android, excel

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            String path =  "/mnt/sda/sda2/";
            //File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
            File exportDir = new File(path, "");

            if (!exportDir.exists()) { exportDir.mkdirs(); }

            File file;
            //file = new File("mnt/sdcard/myfile.csv");

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat Timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.DatePicker);
                String DateStr = datePicker.getYear() + "-" + (datePicker.getMonth()+1) + "-" + datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                Date Local_Time = Timeformat.parse(DateStr);
                DateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Local_Time);

                file = new File(exportDir, "Ticket_"+DateStr +".csv");

                System.out.println("ExportExcel DateStr="+DateStr);
                file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("2");
                CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));

                DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(UltilityActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
                myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(UltilityActivity.this);
                try { 
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
                } catch (IOException ioe) { 
                throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
                }  
                try {  
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
                }catch(SQLException sqle){  
                throw sqle;  
                }
                SQLiteDatabase myExcelDatabase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String Query = 
                    "select tbl_vehicle.Plat_No,Driver_Code,Route_Code,Ticket_Date,tbl_inout.Trip_No,tbl_ticket.In_Out,tbl_ticket.Ticket_No,ref_pricetype.PriceTypeName,tbl_ticket.Amount,loc1.Location_Name as From_Name,loc2.Location_Name as To_Name,Login_Time,Logout_Time "
                    +"from tbl_ticket LEFT JOIN tbl_routeid ON tbl_routeid._id = tbl_ticket.Route_ID "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_driver ON tbl_driver._id = tbl_ticket.Driver_ID                "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle ON tbl_vehicle._id = tbl_ticket.Vehicle_ID             "
                    +"LEFT JOIN ref_pricetype ON ref_pricetype._id = tbl_ticket.PriceType_ID       "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_location loc1 ON loc1.Location_ID = tbl_ticket.From_LocationID "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_location loc2 ON loc2.Location_ID = tbl_ticket.To_LocationID   "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_inout ON tbl_inout._id = tbl_ticket.Trip_ID                    "
                    +"LEFT JOIN tbl_driverlogin ON tbl_driverlogin._id = tbl_inout.Login_ID        "
                    +"WHERE date(tbl_ticket.Ticket_Date) = date('2014-03-20')                      "
                    +"ORDER BY tbl_ticket.Ticket_Date                                              ";
                System.out.println("3");
                Cursor curCSV = myExcelDatabase.rawQuery(Query,null);
                System.out.println("ExportExcel Cursor Count="+curCSV.getCount());
                csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

                double TotalAmount = 0;
                while(curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                    TotalAmount = TotalAmount + curCSV.getDouble(curCSV.getColumnIndex("Amount"));
                    String arrStr[] ={
                            curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1),curCSV.getString(2),curCSV.getString(3),
                            curCSV.getString(4),curCSV.getString(5),curCSV.getString(6),curCSV.getString(7),
                            curCSV.getString(8),curCSV.getString(9),curCSV.getString(10),curCSV.getString(11),
                            curCSV.getString(12)
                            };

                    // curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4)};
                    csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                }
                String arrStr[] ={
                        "","","","","","","","","","","","",""
                };
                arrStr[0] = "Transaction Total ="+curCSV.getCount();
                arrStr[curCSV.getColumnIndex("Amount")] = "Total = RM "+String.format("%.2f",(TotalAmount));
                csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
                csvWrite.close();
                curCSV.close();
                return true;
            } catch(Exception sqlEx) {
                Log.d("Export Excel ", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

this is my code to export database become excel format.But unfortunately the column size are too small 
[image]

I Would like automatically to set the column size with column's maximum text size, mean can show every words in the column, wont be hided the data.

how to set the column size with OpenCSV? automatically set the max text fields size or manually set also can

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to *set the column size* because the
the csv fileformat has no concept of formatting issues like cellcolor or collumn-width.

may be you can try to create an excel-friendly html file instead of csv.